# How to add role based auth to Nextjs with Next-auth & firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I'm currently working on implementing role-based authentication using NextAuth.js in my Next.js application. I've followed the documentation provided by NextAuth.js, but I encountered an error(in profile snippet and callback snippet which i copied from next-auth documentation) when trying to add role-based authentication to my API routes.

I'm using TypeScript and my API route file is located at pages/api/auth/[..nextauth]/route.ts.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import {signInWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth';
import auth from '@/app/lib/auth';


export const authOptions = {
 
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin'
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt" as const,
    maxAge: 3600,
  },

  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      //error
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          role: profile.role ?? "user",
        }
      },
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials): Promise<any> {
        return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, (credentials as any).email || '', (credentials as any).password || '')
          .then(userCredential => {
            if (userCredential.user) {
              return userCredential.user;
            }
            return null;
          })
          .catch(error => (console.log(error)))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
      }
    })
  ],
//error 
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) token.role = user.role;
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session?.user) session.user.role = token.role;
      return session;
    },
  },
}
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

Could someone please help me understand why this error is happening and how I can properly implement role-based authentication with NextAuth.js in my API routes?

What I Tried:

- Using NextAuth.js Documentation: I'm setting up role-based authentication in my Next.js app by following the NextAuth.js documentation.
- Copying Code: I copied code snippets from the documentation to implement role-based authentication.
- Encountering Error: After implementing the code, I encountered an error.

Comment: What is the error you encountered?

Comment: error in profile snippet & callback snippet which important to Role based auth in next-auth

Comment: What is your next auth route? If you are using app directory, it should be `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`. Rename it, and it shall work fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using nextjs version 14 you need the next auth file route like this -- "pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js". maybe that will solve the issue.

link for the documentataion:  [click here](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/adapters/firebase)

Comment: im using app router so changing that to  /[...nextauth].js may led to another error by redirecting signin page to /app/api/auth/error url i think.

Comment: i am also using app router and this works fine with me.

Comment: when i rename that and click sign in button it redirect me to  http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error? so it's led to another error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { error } from "console";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { db } from "@/lib/prismadb";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error("invalid credentials");
        }

        const user = await db.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });

        if (!user || !user?.password) {
          throw new Error("invalid credentials");
        }

        const isCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.password
        );

        if (!isCorrect) {
          throw new Error("invalid credentials");
        }

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

my auth otpions in pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts -- if you using ts make the [...nextauth] file typescript. works like charm for me